# How to display the accurate sum when using 2 inner joins?

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join

I am trying to get the results:

> Quote = 12345
>   Total Assets = 14
>   Total Ordered = 22

When I run the queries separately I get the correct results, but when I put the two queries together my results are off (this is because the tables b and c do not represent each other)

my table summaries are as follows:

```
Select a.Quote, SUM(b.Quantity) As 'Total Assets'
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON b.aId = a.Id
GROUP By a.Quote
```

> Result:  12345 : 14

```
Select a.Quote, SUM(c.Quantity) As 'Total Ordered'
FROM a
INNER JOIN c on c.aId = a.Id
GROUP By a.Quote
```

> Result: 12345 :  22

However, when I put them together:

```
Select a.Quote, SUM(b.Quantity)As 'Total Assets',SUM(c.Quantity) As 'Total Ordered'
FROM a
INNER JOIN b on b.Aid = a.Id
INNER JOIN c on c.Aid = a.Id
GROUP BY a.Quote
```

> Result 12345 : 56 : 308

I played with the group by but was never able to get the proper result. Any thoughts?

So far the solution I came up with is

```
With abc AS
(
 Select a.Quote, SUM(b.Quantity) As 'Total Assets'
    FROM a 
    INNER JOIN b ON b.aId = a.Id
    GROUP By a.Quote
)
SELECT abc.* , SUM(c.Quantity) As ' Total Ordered'
FROM abc
INNER JOIN c ON c.aid = a.Id
GROUP BY (all in abc)
```

It doesn't seem like the best way to get the results though..

Comment: Your JOIN c ON clause uses two columns on c for joining. Are you sure you don't want to join with "a.Id = c.aId"?

Comment: Please describe what you trying to do to get a "proper result". Also, showing the column definitions of tables a, b & c would help along with their respective row counts.

Comment: @druidicwyrm correct, sorry I will fix this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use Left JOIN. The INNER JOIN will repeat rows of b and c. Also, try to see the result of:

```
Select a.Quote, b.Quantity As 'Total Assets', c.Quantity As 'Total Ordered'
FROM a
INNER JOIN b on b.Aid = b.Id
INNER JOIN c on c.Aid = c.Id
GROUP BY a.Quote
```

And check if it's the right results that are computed. Then compare it against:

```
Select a.Quote, b.Quantity As 'Total Assets', c.Quantity As 'Total Ordered'
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b on b.Aid = b.Id
LEFT JOIN c on c.Aid = c.Id
GROUP BY a.Quote
```